# How to merge two dfs in pandas (based on datetime period), and add rows if duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, data-science

I have the following 2 dfs:

#### `diag`

| **id** | **encounter_key** | **start_of_period** | **end_of_period** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | 2020-06-12 | 2021-07-07 |
| 1 | BBB | 2021-12-31 | 2022-01-04 |

#### `drug`

| **id** | **start_datetime** | **drug** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-06-16 | Mel |
| 1 | 2020-06-18 | Mel |
| 1 | 2020-06-18 | Flu |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | Mel |

I want to combine (?merge/?join/?concatenate) the cols of `drug` where the `start_datetime` is within the start and end periods (inclusive) of `diag`, ending up with more rows in `diag` like:

| **id** | **encounter_key** | **start_of_period** | **end_of_period** | **drug** | **start_datetime** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AAA | 2020-06-12 | 2021-07-07 | Mel | 2020-06-16 |
| 1 | AAA | 2020-06-12 | 2021-07-07 | Mel | 2020-06-18 |
| 1 | AAA | 2020-06-12 | 2021-07-07 | Flu | 2020-06-18 |
| 1 | BBB | 2021-12-31 | 2022-01-04 | Mel | 2022-01-01 |

Hope this makes sense and apologies for not using the correct terms - I'm unsure of them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get what you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I duplicate the columns the required number of times, and connect the dataframe again. Then connecting both dataframes together. Perhaps someone will offer a better solution.

```
out = diag[1:]
diag = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(diag.values[:1], 3, axis=0), columns=diag.columns).astype(diag.dtypes)
diag = diag.append(out, ignore_index=True)
df = pd.concat([diag, drug], axis=1)
df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]
df = df.reindex(columns=['id', 'encounter_key', 'start_of_period', 'end_of_period', 'drug', 'start_datetime'])
```

Output

```
   id encounter_key start_of_period end_of_period drug start_datetime
0   1           AAA      2020-06-12    2021-07-07  Mel     2020-06-16
1   1           AAA      2020-06-12    2021-07-07  Mel     2020-06-18
2   1           AAA      2020-06-12    2021-07-07  Flu     2020-06-18
3   1           BBB      2021-12-31    2022-01-04  Mel     2022-01-01
```